# Can I use outer product of reproducing kernel functions $\sum_i |k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)|$ as identity operator in RKHS?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, orthonormal

In a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, given a complete orthonormal basis $\{|e_i\rangle\}$, the identity operator can be written as $\mathbb{1} = \sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|$. Now if this Hilbert space is reproducing, can I write the identity operator as $\mathbb{1} = \sum_i |k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)|$ (or an integral as $\int dx |k_{x}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x}(\cdot)|$), where $|k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)\rangle=|k(x_{i},\cdot)\rangle$ is the reproducing kernel function? (I know they are not orthonormal since the kernal gramian matrix $k(x_i,x_j)\neq\delta_{ij}$ in general, but I just want to know whether I can still plug in $\sum_i |k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)|$ at anywhere in an equation, just as I can do with $\sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|$.)

If not, why the following proof is wrong?

$\forall |\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$, $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|\psi\rangle$, now the inner product $\langle e_i|\psi\rangle$ may be expressed as $\int e_i^*(x)\psi(x)dx$ (or a summation $\sum_j e_i^*(x_j)\psi(x_j)$), but since $k(x_{i},\cdot)$ is reproducing, we should have $\langle e_i|\psi\rangle=\int dx\langle e_i|k_x\rangle\langle k_x|\psi\rangle$, so $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|\psi\rangle=\int dx\sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i|k_x\rangle\langle k_x|\psi\rangle$, now since $\sum_i |e_i\rangle\langle e_i| =\mathbb{1}$, we have $|\psi\rangle=\int dx|k_x\rangle\langle k_x|\psi\rangle$, which is valid for all $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$, hence $\int dx|k_x\rangle\langle k_x|=\mathbb{1}$.

If yes, there seems to be a strange contradiction:

Consider the kernel Gramian matrix's elements $G_{ij}=k(x_i,x_j)=\langle k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)|k_{x_{j}}(\cdot)\rangle$, now if I plugin $\mathbb{1} = \sum_m |k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)|$ between the inner product, I will have $G_{ij}=\sum_m \langle k_{x_{i}}(\cdot)|k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)|k_{x_{j}}(\cdot)\rangle=\sum_m k(x_i,x_m) k(x_m,x_j)=G_{im}G_{mj}$, so that means $G=G^2$ or $G=G^n, \forall n$, which means that all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $G$ must satisfy $\lambda_i^n=\lambda, \forall n$, so all eigenvalues of kernel Gramian matrix $G$ must be $1$ or $0$, which is apparently wrong.

So I must be wrong somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reproducing property only says that $v \mapsto \langle K_{x},v\rangle$ is a bounded linear operator and that $\forall i,\langle K_{x},v\rangle = 0 \implies v=0$, so that $v$ can be seen as a function $v(x)$

Comment: As you suggested, if $\mathbb{1} = \sum_m |k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)|$ then $G$ is unitary (orthonormal) and its eigenvalues have absolute value $1$, no contradiction here

Comment: Sorry, but if you map an element $v$ in Hilbert space to an inner product $\langle K_{x},v\rangle$ which is a real or complex number, this is a functional instead of a linear operator.

Comment: But as you know, kernel gram matrix usually has eigenvalue greater or much less than 1, at least in data science.

Comment: In general $\sum_m |k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)\rangle\langle k_{x_{m}}(\cdot)|$ (if $\sum$ over the $x_m$ means something) is not the identity at all. You should take some examples of RKHS. And $ v \mapsto \langle K_{x},v\rangle$ is a linear functional, a linear operator, a linear form